# Display Search By Symbol Results in a tab/window

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

`Ctrl+Alt+N` allows you to search by symbol. However, it only displays the result in a paginated way in a small popup. Is there a way to show all the results at once in the Find tab/window like if you were doing a global search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the pin icon on the right side of the search popup (= `Show all in view`)

[image]